# Search items in a list in DataFrame when list are stored in rows

Tags: python, list, search, pandas, dataframe

Ok, the name is very confusing but the task is rather simple. I have a pandas data frame like the below and I'd like to perform individual search or items in the lists contained in columns B (there is also a representation as string in C in case can turn out useful)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': [[x,x+1] for x in range(10)]})
>>> df['C'] = df['B'].astype(str)
>>> print df
   A        B        C
0  0   [0, 1]   [0, 1]
1  1   [1, 2]   [1, 2]
2  2   [2, 3]   [2, 3]
3  3   [3, 4]   [3, 4]
4  4   [4, 5]   [4, 5]
5  5   [5, 6]   [5, 6]
6  6   [6, 7]   [6, 7]
7  7   [7, 8]   [7, 8]
8  8   [8, 9]   [8, 9]
9  9  [9, 10]  [9, 10]
```

For example I want to select rows for values 1,7 and return the following rows:

```
print magic_search([1,7], 'B', df)
   A        B        C
0  0   [0, 1]   [0, 1]
1  1   [1, 2]   [1, 2]
6  6   [6, 7]   [6, 7]
7  7   [7, 8]   [7, 8]
```

If I'm looking only for value zero, the following:

```
print magic_search([0], 'B', df)
   A        B        C
0  0   [0, 1]   [0, 1]
```

A **not efficient** solution can be the following:

```
def not_so_magic_search(srchs, col, df):
    bools = pd.concat([df[col].apply(lambda x: srch in x) for srch in srchs],axis=1)
    return df[bools.sum(axis=1) > 0]

>>> not_so_magic_search([1,7], 'B', df)
   A       B       C
0  0  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
1  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
6  6  [6, 7]  [6, 7]
7  7  [7, 8]  [7, 8]
```

The problem is that is terrible as you need to apply the lambda to each row and it just won't scale. I need to do it **efficiently**, as the original DataFrame has 5 million rows and I need to perform the search many time. Any suggestions or ideas on how to perform this?

Comment: Your problem here is that you are storing non-scalar values as elements this doesn't lend itself to vectorised operations

Comment: Indeed, I'm happy to restructure the data frame eventually in order to benefits from vectorisation... not sure how though...

Comment: I did something similar recently and actually the string representation turned out to be easiest.

Comment: @Alessandro, does your index or column A always coincides with the first element of the lists in B ? If so there is an answer below.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel thanks for spending time in this. Unfortunately the index doesn't coincide with the columns and also the list within the row can have one or two or more elements...